# How to get Current User using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve a way to call the current user logged in info because I am going to make and if and else statement inside the AppJs to see if, he is a member he can see the user page if not he cannot or be redirected to the home page
How I store my data:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/authActions';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { Button, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      storeUrl: '',
      errors: {},
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/backoffice');
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push('/backoffice');
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors,
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      storeUrl: this.state.storeUrl,
    };
    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };
  render() {
    const { storeUrl, errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className='container-fluid'>
          <div className='row no-gutter'>
            <div className='d-none d-md-flex align-items-center col-md-4 col-lg-6 bg-image'>
              <div className='vd-hero vd-hero--transparent'>
                <img
                  src={require('../../img/logo.svg')}
                  alt=''
                  className='logo mx-auto'
                />
                <h1 className='vd-hero-headline'>
                  Join 25,000+ retailers already growing their business with
                  PosHub
                </h1>
              </div>
              <img
                src={require('../../img/signup-bag.svg')}
                srcSet={require('../../img/signup-bag.svg')}
                sizes='(max-width: 1400px) 1000px,
                    2000px'
                className='signup-bag'
                alt=''
              />
              <div className='curve'></div>
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-8 col-lg-6'>
              <div className='d-flex justify-content-between'>
                <div className='backHome'>
                  <i className='primaryBlue fa fa-arrow-circle-left'></i>{' '}
                  <Link to='/' className='underline'>
                    Back to Home
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className='sign-in'>
                  Not registered?{' '}
                  <Link to='/register' className='underline'>
                    Sign up now
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='login d-flex align-items-center pb-5'>
                <div className='container'>
                  <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-10 mx-auto'>
                      <div className='vd-hero vd-hero--transparent'>
                        <h1 className='vd-hero-headline h1-customize'>
                          Log in to your account
                        </h1>
                      </div>
                      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <Form.Row>
                          <Form.Group as={Col}>
                            <Form.Label>Store URL</Form.Label>
                            <div className='suffix'>
                              <Form.Control
                                type='url'
                                id='storeUrl'
                                placeholder='Enter storeUrl'
                                value={storeUrl}
                                error={errors.storeUrl}
                                autoComplete='something-unsupported'
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                                className={classnames('form-control', {
                                  invalid: errors.storeUrl,
                                })}
                              />
                              <span className='red-text'>
                                {errors.storeUrl}
                                {errors.storeUrlnotfound}
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>
                        <Button
                          className='btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg'
                          variant='primary'
                          type='submit'
                        >
                          Log In
                        </Button>
                      </Form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './components/layout/Home';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import User from './components/layout/users/User';
import AddUser from './components/layout/users/AddUser';
import EditUser from './components/layout/users/EditUser';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import setAuthToken from './util/setAuthToken';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from './actions/authActions';

if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = './login';
  }
}
 const {user } = this.users


function App() {

  return (

    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          {/* <NavBar /> */}
          <Route path='/forget/password' component={ForgotPassword} exact />

          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={HomePage} exact />
            <Route path='/register' component={Register} exact />
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact />
            <Route path='/backoffice' component={Home} exact />
            {/* Transaction */}
            <PrivateRoute path='/transactions' component={Transactions} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/new'
              component={AddTransactions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/edit/:id'
              component={EditTransactions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/returns'
              component={Returns}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/returns/new'
              component={AddReturns}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/returns/edit/:id'
              component={EditReturns}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/preorders'
              component={PreOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/preorders/new'
              component={AddPreOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/transactions/preorders/edit/:id'
              component={EditPreOrders}
              exact
            />

            {/* Loyalty */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/loyalty/cashbackQuota'
              component={CashBack}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/loyalty/settings'
              component={LSettings}
              exact
            />

            {/* Projects */}
            <PrivateRoute path='/products' component={Products} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path='/products/new' component={AddProducts} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/edit/:id'
              component={EditProducts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/pricebooks'
              component={PriceBooks}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/pricebooks/new'
              component={AddPriceBooks}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/pricebooks/edit/:id'
              component={EditPriceBooks}
              exact
            />
            {/* onlinonlineStore */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/gettingStarted'
              component={GettingStarted}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/orders'
              component={OnlineOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/orders/new'
              component={AddOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/orders/edit/:id'
              component={EditOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/appearance'
              component={Appearance}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/setup'
              component={OnlineStoreSetup}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/marketing'
              component={OnlineMarketing}
              exact
            />

            <PrivateRoute
              path='/onlineStore/payouts'
              component={OnlinePayouts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/qrordering' component={QROrder} exact />
            {/* Send SMS */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/suppliers'
              component={Suppliers}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/suppliers/new'
              component={AddSupplier}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/products/suppliers/edit/:id'
              component={EditSupplier}
              exact
            />
            {/* Stocks */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/supplyNeeds'
              component={SupplyNeeds}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/supplyNeeds/new'
              component={AddSupplyNeeds}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/supplyNeeds/edit/:id'
              component={EditSupplyNeeds}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/purchaseOrders'
              component={PurchaseOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/purchaseOrders/new'
              component={AddPurchaseOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/purchaseOrders/edit/:id'
              component={EditPurchaseOrders}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockReturn'
              component={StockReturn}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockReturn/new'
              component={AddStockReturn}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockReturn/edit/:id'
              component={EditStockReturn}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stocktakes'
              component={StockTakes}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockTransfers'
              component={StockTransfers}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockTransfers/new'
              component={AddStockTransfer}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/stockTransfers/edit/:id'
              component={EditStockTransfer}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/stocks/auditTrail'
              component={AuditTrail}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/promotions' component={Promotions} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/promotions/new'
              component={AddPromotions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/promotions/edit/:id'
              component={EditPromotions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/promotions/cfds' component={Cfds} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path='/customers' component={Customers} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/customers/new'
              component={AddCustomers}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/customers/edit/:id'
              component={EditCustomers}
              exact
            />
            {/* Report */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/over-time'
              component={OverTime}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/product'
              component={ProductSales}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/category'
              component={Category}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/variant'
              component={Variant}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/reports/sales/sku' component={Sku} exact />
            {/* Profile */}
            {/* <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/employee'
              component={Profile}
              exact
            /> */}
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/employee'
              component={SaleEmployee}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/transaction-channel'
              component={TransactionC}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/payment-method'
              component={PaymentMethod}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/sales/shifts'
              component={Shifts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/loyalty'
              component={ReportLoyal}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/products/stockValue'
              component={StockValue}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/products/pre-order'
              component={PreOrdersReport}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/promotions'
              component={ReportPromotions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/reports/bir/pos' component={POSReport} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/reports/bir/zreadings'
              component={ZReadReport}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/employees' component={Employees} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path='/employees/new' component={AddEmployee} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/employees/edit/:id'
              component={EditEmployee}
              exact
            />

            <PrivateRoute
              path='/employees/timesheets'
              component={Timesheets}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/employees/performance'
              component={EmployeePerformance}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/employees/activityLog'
              component={ActivityLog}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/settings/account' component={Accounts} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path='/settings/tax' component={Tax} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/paymentOptions'
              component={PaymentOptions}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/billing/plans'
              component={BillingPlans}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/billing/sms'
              component={SmsPOS}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/stores'
              component={SettingsStore}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/stores/new'
              component={AddSettingsStore}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/stores/edit/:id'
              component={EditSettingsStore}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/bank-accounts'
              component={BankAccounts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/bank-accounts/new'
              component={AddBankAccounts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/bank-accounts/edit/:id'
              component={EditBankAccounts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/receipts'
              component={Receipts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/receipts/new'
              component={AddReceipts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/receipts/edit/:id'
              component={EditReceipts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/registers'
              component={Registers}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/settings/ipad-layouts'
              component={IpadLayouts}
              exact
            />
            <PrivateRoute path='/settings/addOns' component={AddOns} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path='/support/help' component={Help} exact />
            <PrivateRoute
              path='/support/featureRequest'
              component={FeatureRequest}
              exact
            />

{user.status === 'Member' ? (
    <>
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users" component={User} exact />
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users/create" component={AddUser} exact />
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users/edit/:id" component={EditUser} exact />
    </>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/backoffice" />
  )}
        

            {/* HomePage */}
            <Route path='/pricing' component={PricingPlans} exact />
            <Route path='/multi-store' component={MultiStore} exact />
            <Route path='/why-choose-poshub' component={WhyPosHub} exact />
            {/* Navbar Right */}
            <Route path='/contact-sales' component={ContactSales} exact />
            <Route path='/get-selling' component={GetSelling} exact />
            <Route path='/examples' component={BusinessTypes} exact />
            <Route
              path='/examples/sports-and-outdoors-pos'
              component={SportsOutdoors}
              exact
            />
            <Route
              path='/examples/homeware-and-gift-shop-pos'
              component={HomewareStores}
              exact
            />
            <Route
              path='/examples/fashion-boutique-pos'
              component={FashionBoutique}
              exact
            />
            <Route path='/grow-more' component={GrowMore} exact />
            <Route path='/add-the-smarts' component={AddSmarts} exact />
            <Route path='/tour' component={FeatureOverview} exact />
            <Route path='/tour/point-of-sale' component={PointOfSale} exact />
            <Route path='/enterprise' component={Enterprise} exact />
            <Route path='/get-started' component={GetStarted} exact />
            <Route path='/retail-resource-hub' component={AllResources} exact />
            <Route
              path='/tour/pos-reporting'
              component={ReportingInsights}
              exact
            />
            <Route path='/tour/hardware-solutions' component={Hardware} exact />
            <Route
              path='/tour/inventory-management-software'
              component={InventoryManagement}
              exact
            />
            <Route
              path='/tour/customer-management-software'
              component={CustomerManagement}
              exact
            />
            <Route path='/tour/pos-support' component={AwardSupport} exact />
            <Route
              path='/tour/ecommerce-solutions'
              component={EcommerceSolutions}
              exact
            />
            <Route
              path='/customers-case-studies'
              component={CaseStudies}
              exact
            />
            <Route
              path='/tour/accept-payments'
              component={AcceptPayments}
              exact
            />
            <Route path='/security' component={Security} exact />
            <Route
              path='/tour/pos-integrations-add-ons'
              component={HomeAddOns}
              exact
            />
            <Route path='/scanner' component={HomeScanner} exact />

          </Switch>

        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}



export default App;
```

But the problem is that it says the user is not defined so how to make a `const` and call it. Thanks for your help

Comment: This is not the part where I can see `user` object. Can you add more code for the first render return? So the whole component

Comment: I dont get what you are trying to say do u have teamviewer so you could check Im so sorry

Comment: So, add your whole component code for this part of code `user.status === 'Member'`. This is the first part of your question

Comment: so basically I will give you the code of the user component??

Comment: Yes. You can put it here or make codesandbox

Comment: ok ok please wait

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sJ1WpaC5 here is the link of the user component code

Comment: Please let me know if you want to see more of my code

Comment: This is not enough. Can you edit your question or make code example anywhere for all related component to this issue. Where you put your routing, store data etc

Comment: ok ok will edit right now

Comment: @Mario Petrovic all that is related to it?? Do u have facebook lets chat there

Comment: No, still this is not enough. Post your code of App.js component. We can keep this here. You need to be precise with posting your question in order for anyone to answer here. This comment chat is getting too long.

Comment: ok ok will post whole code of app.js

Comment: here you go the whole code of app.js

Comment: I see what you are doing. First thing is you should not render routes like that, always decide if you want to render some route in `render` method of Route component. Second, you are extracting `user` from `this.users` i dont think you entered good code in your question. This comments chat i dragging for too long. Just try and make some live example of your project instead of going back and forward with editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom router

```
const UserMemberRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => ((user || {}).status === 'Member' ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/backoffice',
        state: {
          from: props.location
        }
      }}
      />
    )
    )}
  />
);
```

and use this route wherever you needed like

```
<UserMemberRoute path="/admin/users" component={User} exact />
<UserMemberRoute path="/admin/users/create" component={AddUser} exact />
<UserMemberRoute path="/admin/users/edit/:id" component={EditUser} exact />
```

this is the efficient way to achieve custom routes.

Answer (score 1):

`user` object is probably undefined at the beginning.

You should add initial check before you try to access `.status`:

```js
if(!user) {
  return null
};

return {
  user.status === 'Member' ? (
    <>
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users" component={User} exact />
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users/create" component={AddUser} exact />
      <PrivateRoute path="/admin/users/edit/:id" component={EditUser} exact />
    </>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/backoffice" />
  )
}
```

Comment: hello how do u call the current user logged in the page??

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code. Edit your question and add more code so i can provide you with answers

Comment: what do u wanted to see in my code that will help you solve my problem??

Comment: How do you store data in your application? That part of code. Do you store it state, store?

Comment: here is this what you wanted to see??

Comment: Not how you store it in backend, but how you get that data on your FE. Where do you persist that data on front-end

Comment: oh i see sorry will change

Comment: sorry im just new here is this what you wanted to see ??

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility pass props in router - it can be done like this:

```
<Route path={routes.myProfile} component={() => <MyProfile user ={user}/>} />
```

Next in the **MyProfile** component, you have **currentUser** access like **props**.

Also it's valuable to consider that currentUser information are using a lot times across differeent component, so it can be stored in global access like:

- local storage
- context
- redux